# Dynamically getting value for a single DataGrid column

Tags: wpf, image, wpfdatagrid

I have to populate  a particular column of a data grid from wcf service(using Entity framework)and fill with image.WCF service cannot do anything with images ,so I converted the image to bytes of Array(bytes[]). Again I converted it to the image format to populate the data grid.But I am not able assign image values to the cells dynamically.Could any one help me in this regard,it will be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried.

Comment: Thanks devdigital.May I know you were asking about the conversion code or the code where I have tried to assign to columns.

Comment: "But I am not able assign image values to the cells dynamically". This is the part that isn't clear. What format is your image in? and what is the XAML for the DataGrid, and how are you assigning the image to the column? I.e. are you using DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: My image is in byte[] i have previously mentioned,I think I need a Converter to convert the binary values to image for data binding purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your image byte array is exposed as a view model byte[] property called "MyImageBytes" then you can put it into the DataGrid using a DataGridTemplateColumn, as shown here:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyImageTemplate" >
            <Image Source="{Binding MyImageBytes}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image Column" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```